# Change Status Bar not working in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change the text displayed in the status bar in Excel 2015 using VBA. However, it doesn't seem to be updated. The message "Ready" remains there.

```
Function testStatusBar(delay As Long)

Dim progress As Long

For progress = 1 To delay
   Application.StatusBar = "Progress: test ongoing ...." & (progress / delay) & "%"
   DoEvents
Next progress

Application.StatusBar = False

End Function
```

I also tried many answers that where given here on this website for similar questions, however nothing worked. Is something wrong with the code or do I have to change some settings?

Comment: You have to debug your programme using `F8` to find out where the statusbar is repainted with `Ready` message.

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine, but I suspect that you are calling it as a UDF from an Excel cell.   UDFs are not permitted to update the status bar, or make any other changes to the Excel environment.  (Basically, a UDF is allowed to return a value and that's it.)

If you called that function from a piece of VBA code, it works OK, providing you change it to return a value such as:

```
Function testStatusBar(delay As Long) As String

    Dim progress As Long

    For progress = 1 To delay
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: test ongoing ...." & (progress / delay) & "%"
        DoEvents
    Next progress

    Application.StatusBar = False

    testStatusBar = "Finished"

End Function
```

(You could then call it from other VBA code by saying `myReturnValue = testStatusBar(200000)`

Or change it to a Sub instead of a Function, i.e.

```
Sub testStatusBar(delay As Long)

    Dim progress As Long

    For progress = 1 To delay
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: test ongoing ...." & (progress / delay) & "%"
        DoEvents
    Next progress

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

(and then call it by saying `testStatusBar 200000`.)

Comment: Correct, Excel will not let you modify the object model whilst in a function.

Comment: @SMeaden - Pedantically, Functions can make modifications, but Functions **when invoked as User-Defined-Functions** can't.  So the OP's Function does make changes to the status bar providing it is called from some other (non-UDF!) VBA code.  Similarly, while Subs can normally update the environment, they can't when called from a UDF.